# Wordpress converts my less than sign into the escape code

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm inserting this custom code in Appearance > Customize > Custom Code > Custom JS:

```
for (i=0; i<arr.length; i++) { 
    console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

However, this ends up giving me a syntax error. When I check to see if the javascript appears correctly in my browser, this is what I get:

```
for (i=0; i&lt;arr.length; i++) { 
    console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

How can I get around this? Thank you!

Comment: You might get an answer here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This isn't a WordPress feature...this is a theme feature. You need to contact the developer of your theme.

Comment: I see.. Ok thanks, will do